# Как сделать коллаж из картинок

Tags: css

Необходимо сделать коллаж из картинок примерно такого вида:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я знаю что слои можно расположить с помощью `z-index`, но не знаю как придать этим картинкам форму окружности, как на картинке, подскажите как это можно сделать

Comment: `translate3d` и `z-index`?

Comment: поискал, но как сделать именно то  что мне нужно не нашел

Comment: подробнее изучай трансформации, примеры https://desandro.github.io/3dtransforms/docs/3d-transform-functions.html

Comment: Вы имели ввиду в фотошоп ?

Comment: @Jean-Claude сайт не доступен, в общем сам разобрался, спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Очевидно же, что за вас никто делать не будет. Тут помогают, а не делают. Изучите более подробно свойства трансформации, перспективы, перемещения и позиционировании, например, тут или в других источниках, коих сотни http://html5book.ru/css3-transform/

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>titile</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <style>
    div {
      background-image: url("http://ibiza-rent-a-car-today.com/images/prepaid-creditcard.jpg");
      height: 154px;
      width: 250px;
      position: absolute;
    }
    .div1 {
      transform: perspective(600px) rotateY(0deg) rotateX(45deg);
    }
    .div2 {
      transform: translateY(75px) translateX(45px) perspective(600px) rotateX(45deg) rotate(25deg);
    }
    .div3 {
      transform: translateY(150px) translateX(45px) perspective(600px) rotateX(45deg) rotate(50deg);
    }
    .div4 {
      transform: translateY(225px) translateX(-45px) translateX(45px) perspective(600px) rotateX(45deg) rotate(75deg);
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>

  <div class="div1"></div>
  <div class="div2"></div>
  <div class="div3"></div>
  <div class="div4"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: это понятно, мне и нужен был пример, так как сам не нашел.